# Display user details once logged in

Tags: php, html, sql

I am tying to display all user details once logged in but nothing shows but the word "array". Also the only thing that does display is the user but not the rest i.e firstname, surname etc.

```
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['user']) {

header("location: login.php");
}
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$conn);
$query = "
    SELECT
        id,
        username,
        firstname,
        surname,
        address1
    FROM users 
    WHERE user = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']['firstname']['surname'] 
    ['address1']."'
     ";
    ?>

    <label for="usermail">User Email</label>
    <h7><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></h7>
    <label for="line2">Line 2</label>
    <h7><?php echo $_SESSION['address1']; ?></h7>
```

login.php file is:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']!=''){header("Location:welcome.php");}
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname='';localhost', 'root', '');

$email=$_POST['mail'];
$password=$_POST['pass'];
if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM users WHERE 
    username=?");
    $sql->execute(array($email));
    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        $p=$r['password'];
        $p_salt=$r['psalt'];
        $id=$r['id'];
    }
    $site_salt="salt1";/
    $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);
    if($p==$salted_hash){
        $_SESSION['user']=$id;
        header("Location:welcome.php");
    }else{
        echo "Username OR Password is Incorrect...";
    }
}
```

Comment: all user details i mean the details of the logged in user only

Comment: where are you defining $_SESSION['user'], show that code

Comment: thats because in your code `$_SESSION['user']` is an array and you cant echo arrays.

Comment: the $_SESSION['user'] is defined in login.php

Comment: Can you post your login.php code?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to complicate things when it can be done in a very simple query.
Welcome.php page

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user']){
$userid = $_SESSION['user'];
}else{
//your redirection;
}
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$conn);
$query = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$userid'");
?>

<label for="usermail">User Email</label>
<h7><?php echo $query['yourcolumnname']; ?></h7>

<label for="line2">Line 2</label>
<h7><?php echo $query['yourcolumnname']; ?></h7>
......
```

To specify more arguments, it will look something like

```
"SELECT * FROM user 
where id = '$userid'
AND useremail = '$useremail'
AND.........")
```

Comment: I assume you at least know how to execute your query correctly.

Comment: edited to match login.php $_SESSION['user'] because the session variable is set by using the column [id]